# How to find illegal or adult contents/links into a user-filled website?

Tags: google-adsense, content, advertising, adult-content

I would like to use adsense on my website. This website is filled by users (they put comments and links). Of course, adsense (and others I guess) does not want to put ads on pages containing illegal/adult content or links that points to that.

So, I want to track these bad contents the most easily possible : Is there a program or a web service to do that ?

Comment: Why don't you just moderate all your comments so you don't have to bother with the spammers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to be sure is to filter/moderate the content.

An alternative solution is to rely on antispam filters, such as [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), to validate the user input. Whenever a content is published, make sure to send the content to Akismet and check for Akismet response to determine if it's ham or spam.

About filtering adult content, you can also implement a very simple filter in your site using a blacklist. List "blocked" words somewhere and check for the presence of any of the words every time a content is published.

Of course, you can chain all these filters altogether.